# How to require a custom key to register in Laravel 8.x

Tags: laravel

I wish to use a variable from `.env` to allow permission for registration. But it's not working... When registering with the correct `Register Key` the validator does not allow registration.

**My form registration**

[image]

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {

        $key = env("REGISTER_KEY",null);

        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'key' => ['required', 'same:'.$key],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: *"But it's not working..."* - That is not descriptive. What is the specific problem you're facing with this code? Also, `env()` should not be used in Controllers, but rather `config()`. If you cache your configuration settings, then `env()` will not work there. You'll need to define a configuration setting, like in `config/app.php`, `'register_key' => env("REGISTER_KEY",null)`, then `config('register_key')` will be available.

Comment: *"the validator does not allow registration."* - Getting a little closer. If you do `dd($errors);` after the validator redirects, what is the specific reason your validation fails?

Comment: @Tim Lewis thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure where to add `dd($errors)` could you be more specific?

Comment: Anywhere in your view, actually. `$errors` is a globally available variable. Load your view, add `dd($errors)` and submit your form. On redirect from your validation, you should see an array. That being said, if the answer below fixed the issue, this is only useful information for future debugging. Cheers!

Comment: I think your method also will work if you add a field on request object, `$request->request->add(['check_key' => $key]);` and then the validation will look like `'key' => ['required', 'same:check_key'],`

Comment: Or alternative syntax, `$request->merge(['check_key' => $key])`, then `'key' => ['required', 'same:check_key']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [in](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in) method in the rule :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$key = env("REGISTER_KEY",null);

return Validator::make($data, [
     'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
     'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
     'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
     'key' => [
         Rule::in([$key]),
     ] 
]);
```

Comment: how can I return an error message using `Rule::in()` method?

Comment: You want to return error message on blade template?

Comment: This can help https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors